# makefile not finding the .o file

Tags: c, makefile

I have the strangest problem.
when I run : make tests
in the console I get the following error:
gcc: album_test.o: No such file or directory

[image: makefile]

sorry for attaching the content as a pic,
the site kept giving me a: "Your post appears to contain code that's not properly formatted
as code"

when I change this line :

```
album_test.o: ./tests/album_test.c album.h
```

to be :

```
album_test.o: album_test.c album.h
```

and place the  album_test.c in the same directory as the makefile
everything compiles!

It's very important that the file will be in a separate tests directory.
any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use `make`'s built-in implicit rules to build your object files.  That works when `make` can find the source file in the current directory, but not otherwise.  Update this rule:

```
album_test.o: ./tests/album_test.c album.h
```

To include a recipe:

```
album_test.o: ./tests/album_test.c album.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: You'll have to show some more details about your project layout, then. I made a test project based on your makefile and it seems to work fine with the change I suggest in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But now the make file complains that it can't compile because it can't find the album.h and other .h files that are included into the album.h file.only when I copy all needed .h files to the tests sub-directory, it compiles. but these files must stay in the upper directory.

Comment: Do you have the right paths to include them in `album_test.c`?  Do you pass appropriate `-I` flags otherwise?  They're not in your makefile....

Comment: Carl thanks a lot, I've just missed some rule. your answer was spot on!

Comment: I have a final step to overcome, I was wondering if you might help with that one as well.

in the tests sub directory I'm going to have a lot of test file (like album_test.c)
each with it's own main function.
can the make file compile them all separately to programs while using a single tag/parameter.

for example, can I just write : make tests
and get multiple compiled programs from each _.c file  ?
(similar to the process you mentioned above only many times)

Comment: got it. just gotta use "I ./" to get the makefile search all headers in a specific directory.